# Unique identifier for numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, identifier

I'm in a situation where I have some 2d array `A` that a method one of the classes in my code uses, and then later I need to check if an array passed to a different method has the same values.

The obvious fix is to save `A` as a class attribute, but because `A` can get potentially quite large, I want to avoid adding it as an attribute to avoid memory issues.

What I'd like to do is save some kind of unique identifier for this array and check that. My first thought was to use `id(A)`, but that's a unique identifier to the object, not the array, and so if I have some `B = A.copy()`, it would have a different `id`.

Another thought was to save some sparse version of A, e.g., sample some number of random indices and check equivalence, but that seems a lot more messy and in-depth than I need for something like this.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: When you say "same array" that generally implies *the same object*. So you mean *has the same value*. In any case, does your array continue to exist anyway, because referencing it as an attribute doesn't cost much, only if it would otherwise cease to exist because it is no longer referenced anywhere else.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga - thanks for the terminology correction, edited my post. The array ceases to exist after it is used the first time. The use case is an array used for a `fit` in an sklearn-like estimator i'm writing, that then needs to be checked for equivalence in a `transform` later, if you're familiar with the sklearn API. I don't want to save the original array as an attribute during `fit`.

Comment: Not sure what this means in terms of performance but you could calculate the hash and compare these. Or you create an object where your 2d array is part of and add a flag that you can use... depending if this is something you can use in your methods.

Comment: OK, well one approach would be to save your array to some file format that allows you to read it piece by piece. This may be a bit tricky though, you'll want to avoid text-based serialization formats if you care about binary equality

Comment: @po.pe yeah, a hash could work, e.g. MD5

Comment: Note that for an *arbitrary* object, only its entire information is sufficient to assert equality (otherwise, one could arbitrarily compress anything). If you are looking for a more efficient means of asserting equality, you must describe the important features of your data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [hash function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function) e.g. SHA-256 through `hashlib` module. Example of producing hash-based ID is down below. `array_id()` function returns unique for this array string of fixed 64 symbols length. Array with same contents will produce same id, while if even small portion is changed then it will be totally different id.

Note that different types of array MAY produce different results, e.g. if you have two integer arrays with same integers values but one has type `np.int32` another one is `np.int64` then you'll get different IDs, in this case you just need to change array to one common type e.g. do `res_id = array_id(a.astype(np.int64))`. But different types doesn't always mean that hash IDs will be different, e.g. if all integers are non-negative and less than 2^31 then `np.int32` and `np.uint32` types both will give same hash.

So if you want hash-IDs to be same for numbers of same value then always change array type to some common type like `array_id(a.astype(common_type))` where `common_type` may be e.g. `np.int64` for all integer types and `np.float64` for all floating point types. On the contrary if you want that different types produce always different results then include type name into hash like `hashlib.sha256(str(a.dtype).encode('ascii') + a.tobytes()).hexdigest().upper()`.

In next code if you pass flag `include_dtype = True` then data type will be included in ID computation. If `include_shape = True` also shape will be included. `algo` argument (either `sha256` or `xxhash`) chooses which hash algorithm to use.

Code needs installing some modules one time through command `python -m pip install numpy xxhash`.

[Try it online!](https://repl.it/@moytrage/StackOverflow64753916#main.py)

```
# Needs: python -m pip install numpy xxhash
def array_id(a, *, include_dtype = False, include_shape = False, algo = 'xxhash'):
    data = bytes()
    if include_dtype:
        data += str(a.dtype).encode('ascii')
    data += b','
    if include_shape:
        data += str(a.shape).encode('ascii')
    data += b','
    data += a.tobytes()
    if algo == 'sha256':
        import hashlib
        return hashlib.sha256(data).hexdigest().upper()
    elif algo == 'xxhash':
        import xxhash
        return xxhash.xxh3_64(data).hexdigest().upper()
    else:
        assert False, algo

# Test
import numpy as np, timeit
a = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
print(array_id(a))
print(array_id(a, include_shape = True))
print(array_id(a, include_shape = True, include_dtype = True))

# Speed Measure
a = np.ones((10000, 10000,), dtype = np.uint32)
for algo in ['sha256', 'xxhash']:
    print(algo, round(timeit.timeit(lambda: array_id(a, algo = algo), number = 1), 3), 'sec')
```

Output:

```
17A96F5E5826D66A
E201378DF28CB280
0FDFAE47334C986A
sha256 3.774 sec
xxhash 1.356 sec
```

Comment: This assumes no one finds a collision attack on SHA-256 and uses it against you, though.

Comment: Also, the "different types" issue also extends to arrays of different dtypes and *different* data producing the *same* hash if the in-memory representation happens to match.

Comment: this seems like it scales poorly with array size? I tried it on a 10,000 * 10,000 array and it was taking on the order of minutes to hash.

Comment: @AlexL I didn't know you need to use my code for realy large arrays. I just implemented right now an improved version of my code. You need to install `xxhash` module by `python -m pip install xxhash`, it is very fast hash implementation. I updated my answer with new code, and also did time measurement. Probably you did something wrong, because `10000x10000` array (see my code above, in answer) is hashed (computed ID) just in few seconds, both for old and new hash algorithm! Maybe you included into your time measurement generation of array by some random generator which is slow.

Comment: @AlexL Look into console output of my code above (console output is provided at end of answer). I takes `1.3 seconds` on my slow/old laptop for array of size `10000x10000`. I'm sure you included in your time measurement something very slow besides array-ID computation, it is a common mistake, maybe you included generation of this huge array by random generator, which is usually quite slow. Array ID computation by my code alone is very fast! Try my code above without changes on your PC, it should print Array-ID compute time for array of `10000x10000` size.

Comment: @AlexL Also maybe you forgot to include `number = 1` into `timeit` time measurement code. Because by default it computes function many times when does time measurement. To compute it only once on given input you have to add argument `number = 1` as I did in my code above (in answer). Read my 3 last comments, I provided details about improvements to my algorithm and about correct way of measuring time!